# VHDL for loop always give me the same value

Tags: loops, for-loop, vhdl, clock, rom

What I want to do is add the element `0+11`, then `1+10`, then `2+9` and like this with all the others, but when I'm simulating, it takes just the first elements (0,11). I also thought it will be a good idea to take the values in one clock event but I'm not sure.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Sumador is
Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
en : in  STD_LOGIC;
--actCont : in  STD_LOGIC;
data : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
A,B: inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
C: inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0)
);
end Sumador;

architecture Behavioral of Sumador is
signal addr: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
--signal A,B,C: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);
type arrayRom is array (0 to 11) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

constant memRom: arrayRom:=(
"1111111",--0
"1001111",--1
"0010010",--2
"0000110",--3
"1001100",--4
"0100000",--5
"0001111",--6
"0000000",--7
"0001100",--8
"0000001",--9
"0001000",--10
"0100001"
);

begin                   
process(clk)
begin  
if(RISING_EDGE(clk))then
if(en='1')then
for i in 0 to 11 loop
A<=memRom(i); --here i get the value from the i position of the constant     memory
B<=memRom(11-i);
C<=A+B;
end loop;
data<=C;
else
--A<="0000000";
--B<="0000000";
--C<=A+B;
--data<=C;
data<="0000000";
end if; 
end if; 
end process;
end Behavioral;`enter code here`
```

on test bench

```
enter code here
-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin       
en<='0';
wait for 100 ns;
en<='1';
wait for 100 ns;
en<='0';
wait for 100 ns;
en<='1';
wait for 100 ns;
en<='0';
wait for 100 ns;
en<='1';
wait;
end process;
```

Some simulation results:
[image: Here is the simulation result]
[image: Another one]

Comment: I don't think this question is all that bad.  It exhibits a coding mistake I often see in young engineers that do not understand signal assignment semantics.  Matthew Taylor gave a great answer explaining the assignment in a loop overwriting a previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your design intent is not entirely clear, but I'd say you have two problems here. One is a VHDL problem; one is a general programming problem.

i) The VHDL problem: this code will never do as (I think) you intend:

```
for i in 0 to 11 loop
A<=memRom(i); --here i get the value from the i position of the constant     memory
B<=memRom(11-i);
C<=A+B;
end loop;
data<=C;
```

because `A`, `B` and `C` are VHDL *signals* (any *port* is a signal). VHDL signals are not updated until the process suspends. So, because `A`, `B` and `C` are signals, their values in this line `C<=A+B` will always be the values from the previous time the process was executed, as will be the value of `C` in this line `data<=C`. In this case the previous time the process was executed will have been the previous rising edge of `clk`. So, a solution to this would be to replace `A`, `B` and `C` with *variables*. Variables are just like variables in any other language - their values are updated immediately. So, this is closer:

```
process(clk)
  variable A,B,C : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
begin  
  if RISING_EDGE(clk) then
    if en='1' then
      for i in 0 to 11 loop
        A := memRom(i); --here i get the value from the i position of the constant     memory
        B := memRom(11-i);
        C := A+B;
      end loop;
      data<=C;
```

A VHDL `signal` should be used to communicate *between* processes.

A VHDL `variable` should be used as working memory *within* a process.

However...

ii) The programming problem: as I say I don't know your design intent, but this code is always going to just add elements 0 and 11 and nothing else, because `C` is overwritten on every loop.

Comment: I have also taken the opportunity to indent your code and to remove unnecessary parentheses.